# Django modelformset_factory - how to save multiple records with javascript

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms

I have two buttons "Add" and "remove" they are working fine, i can add and remove forms but the problem is when it comes to submit the forms that i have added it only save the first row in the database. Can any one help please!

Here are my codes!

**view.py**

```
def create_purchase(request):
    OrderItemFormset = modelformset_factory(OrderItem, form=OrderItemForm)
    formset = OrderItemFormset(queryset=OrderItem.objects.none())
    if request.method == "POST":
        form1 = OrderDetailForm(request.POST or None)
        formset = OrderItemFormset(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix='orderitem')
        if form1.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            orderdetail = form1.save()
            items = formset.save(commit=False)
            for item in items:
                item.order_no = orderdetail
                item.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Successfully Saved!', 'alert-success')
            return redirect('v_purchase')
        else:
            context = {
            'form1':form1,
            'formset':formset
            }
            return render(request, 'managepurchase/create_purchase.html', context)

    else:
        form1 = OrderDetailForm()
        formset = OrderItemFormset(queryset=OrderItem.objects.none(), prefix='orderitem')
        context = {
        'form1':form1,
        'formset':formset
        }
        return render(request, 'managepurchase/create_purchase.html', context)
```

**Template**

```
<table id="id_forms_table" border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%">
          <thead>
            <tr>

                <th scope="col" class="text-info">Product</th>
                <th scope="col" class="text-info">Quantity</th>
                <th scope="col" class="text-info">Buying Price</th>
                <th scope="col" class="text-info">Amount</th>
                <th scope="col" class="text-info"></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              {{ formset.management_form }}
              {% for form in formset %}

            <tr id="{{ form.prefix }}-row" class="dynamic-form">

                <td>{{ form.product }}</td>
                <td>{{ form.quantity }}</td>
                <td>{{ form.buying_price }}</td>
                <td>{{ form.amount }}</td>
                <td>
                    <a id="remove-{{ form.prefix }}-row" href="javascript:void(0)" class="delete-row btn btn-info btn-sm" style="color:white"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></a>
                </td>

              </tr>

              {% endfor %}

              <tr>
                <td colspan="4"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="add-row btn btn-info btn-sm" style="color:white"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></a></td>
              </tr>

          </tbody>
      </table>

<script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {
            $('.add-row').click(function() {
                return addForm(this, 'form');
            });
            $('.delete-row').click(function() {
                return deleteForm(this, 'form');
            })
        })
</script>
```

**Javascript**

```
function updateElementIndex(el, prefix, ndx) {
        var id_regex = new RegExp('(' + prefix + '-\\d+)');
        var replacement = prefix + '-' + ndx;
        if ($(el).attr("for")) $(el).attr("for", $(el).attr("for").replace(id_regex, replacement));
        if (el.id) el.id = el.id.replace(id_regex, replacement);
        if (el.name) el.name = el.name.replace(id_regex, replacement);
    }

    function addForm(btn, prefix) {
        var formCount = parseInt($('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val());
        var row = $('.dynamic-form:first').clone(true).get(0);
        $(row).removeAttr('id').insertAfter($('.dynamic-form:last')).children('.hidden').removeClass('hidden');
        $(row).children().not(':last').children().each(function() {
            updateElementIndex(this, prefix, formCount);
            $(this).val('');
        });
        $(row).find('.delete-row').click(function() {
            deleteForm(this, prefix);
        });
        $('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val(formCount + 1);
        return false;
    }

    function deleteForm(btn, prefix) {
        $(btn).parents('.dynamic-form').remove();
        var forms = $('.dynamic-form');
        $('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val(forms.length);
        for (var i=0, formCount=forms.length; i<formCount; i++) {
            $(forms.get(i)).children().not(':last').children().each(function() {
                updateElementIndex(this, prefix, i);
            });
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Where am i wrong or is there any other way i can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, and finally I have a solution for this.
I made it clear in [here](https://gist.github.com/mahdikhi/dc707b802617e517326582b6b9ffc363) how I did that.
you need to pass the total foem-set count to the back-end and tell form-set model what is that count. and when you're save the form1 and its form-sets first you should saving the form1 instance and then for each sub-from in the form-set save that sub-form. of course you can commit the save false and do some work before save.

Comment: all I had done is explained there just follow that link.